# What does docker-ce-cli & containerd.io installation packages install?

Tags: docker

To install docker engine on ubuntu, we run:

```
  sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

But the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) mentions installation instruction as:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

---

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:02:36 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:01:06 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
$ 
$ 
$ ps -eaf | grep contain
root      1704     1  0 10:05 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/containerd
root      2233     1  0 10:05 ?        00:00:04 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
$ 
$
```

---

Is `docker-ce` an installation package for docker daemon/server/engine(only)?

Is `docker-ce-cli` an installation package to install docker client(only)?

Is `containerd.io` an installation package to install containerd component in below architecture?

[image]

Comment: This would be a question for **Docker** because they publish the packages, not Ubuntu.  It's not offtopic, but asking the Docker devs this question might get you faster responses.

Comment: @ThomasWard I did not get you, when you say docker devs. Can you mention the exact site url?

Answer (score 2):

> Is docker-ce an installation package for docker
> daemon/server/engine(only)?
>
> Is docker-ce-cli an installation package to install docker
> client(only)?
>
> Is containerd.io an installation package to install containerd
> component in below architecture?

Yes to all of those. The architecture diagram is pretty clear. Docker itself used to implement all of this into a single binary, but overtime they decided to embrace the [Open Container Initiative](https://opencontainers.org/) (OCI).

`containerd` is one implementation that follows the OCI. It uses kernel features to provide a runtime environment for containers.

`dockerd` talks to `containerd` and also provides more features to Docker users in the form of the easy commands like `docker build`, `docker network`, `docker volume` and `docker inspect`.

`docker-cli` provides the `docker` binary client that talks to the `dockerd` API, on a local socket or remotely. Even without this client, you could still build and run containers by just using the API.